# How to get the Absolute DNN Portal Logo URL Path for use with Microdata?

Tags: dotnetnuke, microdata, dotnetnuke-9

How can I get the current DNN Logo file's Absolute URL Path?

Currently, Google picks up the Relative Path. **/Portals/2/Images/logo.png**

I need the full path with the domain name.

I want something almost like: **PortalSettings.PortalAlias.PortalID**

The Google Structured Data Tool gives the following path after I have added itemprop="logo" to the logo.ascx file found under Admin/Skins in DNN.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the output in Google’s SDTT is your only concern: You don’t need to provide the full URL; every consumer will use the document base URL to end up with the correct, full URL. In the SDTT, Google shows their own base URL because the tool runs there.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the base URL part. I think the Output is not my only concern. I think Google won't detect the Logo URL as the path only actually starts at /Portals/Images/2/Logo.png

Comment: If you have something like `<img itemprop="image" src="/Portals/Images/2/Logo.png" alt="">`, and the image displays in the browser, every Microdata consumer will be able to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following code, but I only still need the protocol which will be http:// or https://

The code below will generate **dnndev.me/Portals/2/Images/logo.png**

I just need to figure out how to get the protocol. I am sure the code below can be simplified.

```
PortalLogoPath = PortalSettings.Current.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias + PortalSettings.HomeDirectory + PortalSettings.LogoFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PortalLogoPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + PortalSettings.Current.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias + PortalSettings.HomeDirectory + PortalSettings.LogoFile;
```